# How to get a list of all folder names under a folder?

Tags: files

I have a folder structure like this,i want get a list that all folder names in pack folder. Then traverse the list and load them

```
├── pack
│   ├── completion
│   │   ├── company
│   │   │   └── pack-company.el
│   │   ├── ivy
│   │   │   └── pack-ivy.el
│   │   └── smartchr
│   │       └── pack-smartchr.el
│   ├── editor
│   │   ├── evil
│   │   │   └── pack-evil.el
│   │   ├── fold
│   │   │   └── pack-fold.el
│   │   └── multiple-cursors
│   │       └── pack-multiple.el
```

list will has `pack/completion/company`, `pack/completion/ivy` etc..

Comment: Do you mean `completion` and `editor`, or all the subdirectories, too?

Comment: @choroba  i update the post, i want get the list which has `pack/completion/company` ,`pack/completion/ivy` ,`pack/editor/evil` etc.,.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/33332/2526

Comment: ??? not  a same problem

Comment: So the result list should NOT contain `pack/completion` and `pack/editor`?

Comment: Not the same problem, so I'm not voting to close your question. It's similar enough, though, and one of the answers is applicable to your situation, too, with just a minor modification.